# Images not showing in WebView on Asus tablets

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have `WebView` in which I'm loading some local html file. On click of a button I'm adding new image that loads in the html (the image file is on the sdcard). I have tested this on 3 different tablets (the application is intended for use on tablets only): Acer Iconia A500, Acer Iconia A501, Samsung Galaxy, Asus tf300, Asus tf700. It is working perfectly on the first 2, but on the Asus tablets there is a problem. Sometimes the image is not shown. Not all the images but only some of them. It doesn't show anything on that place, just the white background :)

**What can be the problem with the Asus tablets?**

**UPDATE:**

I have a button for reloading the html and on click on that button I'm calling `webView.reload()`. I noticed that when I click the button only the images that are visible on the screen at the moment of clicking are shown, the other images are not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find what is the problem. I figured out it is something with the rendering of the images and the view port of the `WebView`.
If I set `setUseWideViewPort(false)`, then change the zoom in and out, and then again set `setUseWideViewPort(true)`, then the images are shown.

**EDIT:**

If that doesn't solve the problem, this can be tried:

```
setUseWideViewPort(false);
zoomIn();
zoomIn();
setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

The last line is not needed if you don't want to use `WideViewPort`

Comment: Can you explain for better understanding?

Comment: When I load local html file in the `WebView` the images are not shown on Asus tablets. And when I do what is explained above, the images appear. Sometimes it is working even if I just zoom in or out with pinch-zoom or click on the zoom in-out buttons. I think the problem is with the `WebView` because this only happens on Asus tablets. On every other device I tried it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: So, you add two lines in webview call. setUseWideViewPort(false) and setUseWideViewPort(true). I faces this problem in samsung devices. Please advise me.

Comment: Yes. Or if that doesn't solve the problem you can try with the code I added in the answer. Hope this helps.